# C# folder, subfolder, and files not coming up in C# windows application directory path comparison code

Tags: c#, windows, subdirectory

For this code, I wanted the user to essentially enter in two directory paths, and compare them if there are any differences in the folders or files, right down to the specific folder or file in a C# Windows Application. The code I have now only goes to the immediate folder, and only list the immediate files if they are inside the immediate folder.

```
private void btnCompare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear previous results.
    dgvFiles.Rows.Clear();

    // Get sorted lists of files in the directories.
    string dir1 = txtDir1.Text;
    if (!dir1.EndsWith("\\")) dir1 += "\\";
    string[] file_names1 = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dir1);
    for (int i = 0; i < file_names1.Length; i++)
    {
        file_names1[i] = file_names1[i].Replace(dir1, "*.*");

    }
    Array.Sort(file_names1);

    string dir2 = txtDir2.Text;
    if (!dir2.EndsWith("\\")) dir2 += "\\";
    string[] file_names2 = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dir2);
    for (int i = 0; i < file_names2.Length; i++)
    {
        file_names2[i] = file_names2[i].Replace(dir2, "*.*");
    }
    Array.Sort(file_names2);

    // Compare.
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while ((i1 < file_names1.Length) && (i2 < file_names2.Length))
    {
        if (file_names1[i1] == file_names2[i2])
        {
            // They match. Display them both.
            dgvFiles.Rows.Add(new Object[] { file_names1[i1], file_names2[i2] });
            i1++;
            i2++;
        }
        else if (file_names1[i1].CompareTo(file_names2[i2]) < 0)
        {
            // Display the directory 1 file.
            dgvFiles.Rows.Add(new Object[] { file_names1[i1], null });
            i1++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Display the directory 2 file.
            dgvFiles.Rows.Add(new Object[] { null, file_names2[i2] });
            i2++;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload of [GetFileSystemEntries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383460(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a further `SearchPattern` string and a `SearchOption` as parameters. This will get you also the subfolders including the files:

```
string[] file_names1 = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dir1, "*",
                       SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! The code returns saying No Overload for Method 'GetFileSystemEntries' takes 3 arguments.

Comment: It should do - as per the linked page

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy this is strange. What Framework version are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2017, if that's any indication of the framework I'm using

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy can you please post the line of how it looks in your code ?

Comment: string[] file_names1 = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dir1, "*",
                       SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: Have you tried to restart Visual Studio?=! VS2017 tends to have some weird extravagances ;)

Comment: Sadly no. I was hoping the saying "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" would work, haha. Will changing the GetFileSystemEntries to Get Directories work?

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy I actually realy thought about writing that :D. "Will changing the GetFileSystemEntries to Get Directories work" unfortunately not really, because then you will have to do through every folder to get the files using `GeFiles`

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy but try it, there is also an overload that takes 3 arguments, Let's see whether this one works ;) really intriguiged now

Comment: It works, but only when it comes to folders. No files. As usual.

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy what a crap. What actually about the overload of `GetFileSystemEntries` taking only 2 parameters ?=! `path` and `searchPattern` ? is this known by your compiler ?

Comment: Can you provide an example? My mind is drawing a blank at the moment.

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(@"C:\temp", "*");`

Comment: It's not throwing up an error for what you suggested.

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy so your compiler knows only one overload for it ?=!

Comment: It's looking like so. I'm so confused as to what is happening within the compiler. Can I have it so it accepts the overload?

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy please click in VS on the project properties. Under the Tab "Application" you will see the [Tragetframework]. This needs to be at least 4.0. Below this version the `GetFileSystemEntries` overloads are not known

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy I need to catch my train. Wish you good luck!

Comment: Holy crap, I think that'll do it. It was set to 3.5 for some reason.

Comment: It works! Boy am I stupid. Seriously just stick a dunce hat on me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy glad to hear that it works. You are welcome. 3.5 is really a waste if you are using VS2017 with all the nice features of C#7 ;)